# Virtual box Android emulator and Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

I start to use this VirtualBox machine as Android emulator in my development:

http://www.buildroid.org/blog/?page_id=121

I install and execute my application in this emulator but when I try to connect to Eclipse using adb connect [my ip address] I found problems.

When I connect my virtual machine with Eclipse using host only network for eth1 my virtual device lost its internet connection. My device access internet only when eth01 network configuration is NAT but with this configuration I can't connect with Eclipse using adb connect.

Any idea about it?

Comment: From a terminal, run ifconfig -eth01 and connect to that IP address

Answer (score 3):

Finally my Virtual Box emulator work and communicate with Eclipse. When I found the correct network configuration all work perfectly.

My correct network configuration is:

Et01: NAT
Et02: Internal network.

In adb -connect I've use the Et01 Ip to connect it with Eclipse.

I hope be usefull!!